# MySQL Query - Loading records if the owner is a friend

Tags: mysql

I've got a system on my website which is very similar to Facebook, where you can post statuses and your people can comment on your status, like it etc. This all gets inserted in the database in the following format, with child tables of the likes and comments with foreign keys set up in case the parent status gets deleted, the likes and comments get deleted with it.

[image: Table: "status"]

I also have a friends table which contains the user ID of the user that started the friend request, the user ID of the user that has to either accept it or deny it, and the status of the record, whether it's accepted, denied or pending.

[image: Table: "friends"]

There's also a "users" table which contains the normal malarkey, such as emails, passwords etc. All records have a unique ID however, in the column "userID".

The query I have at the moment loads all statuses regardless of whether the status owner is your friend or not. The **current** query looks like this (I'm working in ColdFusion so `##` are the variables passed to the function)

```
SELECT *, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM status_likes WHERE likeStatusID=statusID) AS StatusLikeCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM status_comments WHERE SID=statusID) AS StatusCommentCount
FROM status, users
WHERE statusOwner=userID
AND statusType='user'
ORDER BY statusDateTime DESC
LIMIT #args.indexStart#,#args.indexEnd#;
```

I need this query to only load statuses if the owner of the status is your friend. I can call a query to load a users friends and append a string containing the user ID's of all the friends, such as: "652,235,485,975" etc.

I tried doing an `IN` in the query so there was an extra line:

```
AND (statusOwner=#val(args.userID)# OR statusOwner IN (#usersFriendsString#))
```

However this brought back duplicate results and when I tried `GROUP BY` on the status owner, it didn't bring back records that it should have.

Any MySQL gurus out there able to help?

Comment: Please untag "coldfusion". This is strictly a MYSQL question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like that :

```
SELECT 
s.*,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM status_likes WHERE likeStatusID=s.statusID) AS StatusLikeCount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM status_comments WHERE SID=s.statusID) AS StatusCommentCount
FROM Users u
JOIN Friend f ON f.friendOwner = u.id
JOIN Status s ON s.statusOwner = f.id
WHERE u.id = <...>
ORDER BY s.statusDateTime DESC
```

You can use WHERE clause if you can't use a JOIN instruction.

Or you can use a IN instruction populated by a SELECT that retrieve all requiered status ids.